# What is the difference between MS terms for build tools?

Tags: visual-c++

I am confused with MS terms for build tools for C++.

1. They have "Platform toolset"
2. Build Tools
3. MSVC
4. "VCTools"

What is the different? My question is not about MS VS.

I've googled but it is still not clear for me.

Answer (score 0):

MSVC (Microsoft Visual C++):

MSVC is the C++ compiler for Windows development.
It includes the compiler and core tools for building C++ applications.

VCTools (Visual C++ Tools):

VCTools encompasses the entire set of tools and components for C++ development, including the MSVC compiler, libraries, headers, linkers, and runtime components.

Platform Toolset and Build Tools:

Platform Toolset is a specific version of the MSVC compiler/tools used in Visual Studio projects.
Build Tools refer to command-line utilities for building C++ projects without the Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: The term "Platform Toolset" has a stricter definition in the context of the WDK: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/platform-toolset

Comment: MSVC is a part of VCTools?

Comment: Who is a part of whom?